# Problem with random string, Error: 'variable' is not captured

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate random string based on given alphabet.
If I define alphabet in string random_string then it works, but if I want to modify alphabet in main and then send it to function it give's Error: 'alphabet' is not captured.

```
string random_string( size_t length, string alphabet)
{
    auto randchar = []() -> char
    {
        const char charset[] = alphabet;
        const size_t max_index = (sizeof(charset) - 1);
        return charset[ rand() % max_index ];
    };
    string str(length,0);
    generate_n( str.begin(), length, randchar );
    return str;
}
```

In main:

```
string alphabet="ABCDE";
string txt= random_string(150, alphabet);
```

Original Code which works:

```
string random_string( size_t length)
{
    auto randchar = []() -> char
    {
        const char charset[] = "ABCDE";
        const size_t max_index = (sizeof(charset) - 1);
        return charset[ rand() % max_index ];
    };
    string str(length,0);
    generate_n( str.begin(), length, randchar );
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `const char charset[] = alphabet;` -> alphabet is a std::string, there is no direct conversion from std::string to a char[].

Comment: So should I just make a loop txt[i]=alphabet[rand()%4] instead of this function? Might be easier

Comment: Change `const char charset[] = alphabet` to `const char* charset = alphabet.c_str()`.

Comment: And `const size_t max_index = (sizeof(charset) - 1)` to `const size_t max_index = alphabet.length()`.

Comment: @goodvibration Still getting the same error after replacing those 2 lines of code.

Comment: I should have probably mentioned `to begin with`.

Comment: @goodvibration Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be fixed this way:

1) To avoid 'Error: 'alphabet' is not captured.' you should actually capture string `alphabet` into your lambda function: `auto randchar = [&alphabet]() -> char { ... }`. More about lambdas and capturing [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda);

2) Your don't need auxiliary buffer `charset`. If you have already had a reference to string, just get a random symbol from it;

3) Also I added `const` qualifier to string reference, because it's logically constness.

Here the fixed variant is:

```
string random_string( size_t length, const string &alphabet)
{
  auto randchar = [&alphabet]() -> char
    {
        const size_t max_index = (alphabet.size() - 1);
        return alphabet[ rand() % max_index ];
    };
    string str(length,0);
    generate_n( str.begin(), length, randchar );
    return str;
}
```